# SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have the following method for retrieving messages from Gmail using imap

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        try
        {
            props.load(new FileInputStream(new File("smtp.properties")));
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

            Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
            store.connect("smtp.gmail.com", "******@gmail.com", "mypass");

            Folder inbox = store.getFolder("inbox");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            int messageCount = inbox.getMessageCount();

            Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages();
            System.out.println("------------------------------");
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Mail Subject:- " + messages[i].getSubject());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

my smtp.properties contains

```
 mail.smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
 mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=465
 mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
 mail.smtp.auth=true
 mail.smtp.port=465
```

I get the following when I run the program

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Remote host closed connection during handshake;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:695)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:345)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:226)
    at gmailsmpt.Main.main(Main.java:25)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:532)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:337)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:229)
    at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:116)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.<init>(IMAPProtocol.java:121)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.newIMAPProtocol(IMAPStore.java:710)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:659)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    ... 14 more
```

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Try running with `-Djavax.net.debug=all` to get a better idea during what phase of the handshake the connection is closing.

Comment: Why are you using SMTP properties for an IMAP connection?

Comment: are you following http://www.technicalkeeda.com/java/how-to-access-gmail-inbox-using-java-imap

Comment: @SpringLearner yes, that is what I followed

Comment: @EJP wow good catch, I followed a tutorial online and I never thought they would have the wrong server. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

First, clean up all these [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).  You don't need any socket factories.

Then try these [connection debugging tips](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).

Possibly you have a firewall or anti-virus program that's preventing you from connecting.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the default TLS version in JAVA jre1.8.0_141 1.0, however due to vulnerabilities in 1.0 a lot of email servers no longer accept connections. To instead use 1.2 directly in code this instruction worked for me when creating properties for sending mail:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
```

For example:

```java
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", mailHost);
props.put("mail.smtps.auth", mailAuth);
props.put("mail.transport.protocol", mailProtocol);
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2");

// Get a Session object
Session sess = Session.getInstance(props, null);

// construct the message
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(sess);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(mailUser));
```

Also note, you could just set that same property in the properties file you're loading (`smtp.properties`) at the start of your `try` block.

Answer (score 0):

Are there more stacktraces? Older Java versions have problems with TLS handshakes with RSA keys with more than 1024 bit (may be also with keys having exactly bit byte).

This was fixed in Java 1.7 or Java 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

try adding below to the properties:
properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");